# SQL Server : find rows that contains spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm looking for fast way to see all rows in table that contains any spaces.

For starters, I tried to see which rows starts with space by this query:

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where ColumnName like ' %'
```

but I got 0 results, although I can see there are rows with spaces.

Comment: What did you get when you run `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LEFT(ColumnName, 1) = ' '`? if it returns 0 rows then it's not a white space as you think. I suggest to use `SELECT ASCII(LEFT(Column, 1)) ..`

Comment: What you see as a space may not actually be a space.  You may want to look at the binary value to determine what character is actually there.

Comment: Are you looking for rows that start with a space, or contain a space? If it's the latter, then you should use `select * from MyTable where ColumnName like '% %'`

Comment: @Sami: i try it but it bring only rows which start with unknown chars (��) ; Gordon: i know for sure there is spaces in data of this table; daShier: i try it too but 0 results.

Comment: Can you provide sample data including a CREATE TABLE script to ensure we're all discussing the same data types?

Answer (score 13):

Give this a try:

**In SQL server you can use this:**

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',ColumnName) > 0;
```

**If you are using Oracle you can use this:**

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE INSTR(ColumnName,' ') > 0;
```

Essentially in this query it finds the character position containing first space from the column values and when it finds the first space in it the index value should be greater than 1 and it should display all the records based on that.

Comment: In DB2 you can use `LOCATE`

Answer (score 3):

Seem that those space contain some other special character apart from char(10).

Try this,

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where patindex('%[^A-Z0-9]%',ColumnName )>0
```

First decide what is valid value for ColumnName .Then try `PATINDEX` and change the regex accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot! i try TRIM but it still dont remove the line's starting spaces, so i cheak for those starting spaces and relize they somehow different then regular space  (' ' vs ' '). i try now by REPLACE command with cut/paste this weird space.

Answer (score 1):

try put another '%', this may solve your problem.

`select *  from MyTable  where ColumnName like '% %'`

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from TABLE where trim(column_name) IS NULL
```

Comment: On SQL Server an empty string is not the same as null. This answer is incorrect as I believe you've misinterpreted the question in the first place.